# How to send JSON as respond from Node js to Html file

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

I'm trying to send JSON from Node js to html file as a response, but after I submit HTML form disapears and this shows up [Respond after I submit a form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVOIz.png). I tried ajax but it doesn't work beacuse I get redirected to this (image above). I'm trying to make a simple login form and if user inputs nothing then message should get displayed saying "Nothing was input" below the form.

JS code (node.js, express framework)

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/Frontend/html/login.html'));
});

app.post('/login', function(req, res){
    res.json({a: 5});
});
```

html code

```
 <form method="POST">
    <input type = "text" name = "username" id = "username" placeholder="Username">
    <input type = "password" name = "password" id = "password" placeholder="Password">
    <button id = "gumb" type = "submit">Prijavi se</button>
</form>
<p id = "demo"></p>
<script>
    document.getElementById('gumb').addEventListener('click', function(){
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        console.log("test");

        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
           document.write(xhr.responseText);
        }
        else{
            console.log("broke");
        }

        xhr.open('get', 'http://localhost:8000/login', true);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It works as excepted. It returns `{a: 5}` JSON data when you POST to `/login` endpoint.

Comment: You are not rendering any template or redirecting to anywhere after that.

Comment: yes but does it return like shown in the picture?

Comment: Hum, yes. I don't understand your question. The picture shows raw JSON data displayed in your browser.

Comment: this is the question why does it display raw JSON data display, why doesn't it display form?

Comment: I answered that in my second comment. [res.json](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.json) end the request with raw data.

Comment: Yes, what should I use to make this work

Answer (score 0):

Your code works as expected, you just send a json key-value pair to your frontend, when the route is invoked. The data is shown in your browser.

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res){
    res.json({a: 5});
});
```

---

Usually, you would want to do something with the data sent to your backend:

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res){
  user= req.body.username;
  password = req.body.password;
  console.log(`User: ${user} is requesting login`);
  // do something with the data - login, save, edit
  res.end();
});
```

---

Since you obviously commit login data (FROM a form TO your backend),
you should use some authentification middleware to perform a login.

To comfortably send processed html to your backend, you should get acquainted with the subject of **views**.

And the express api documentation will be **very** useful to you, I'm sure. ;)

https://expressjs.com/en/api.html

Comment: Thanks for response, but all I'm tryint to do is to send a message after user submit a form to frontend to display error etc